# i got this msg each time"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at GradesAverage.main(GradesAverage.java:31)"

Tags: java

*/Write a program called GradesAverage, which prompts user for the number of students, reads it from the keyboard, and saves it in an int variable called numStudents. It then prompts user for the grades of each of the students and saves them in an int array called grades.  Your program shall check that the grade is between 0 and 100./*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesAverage{

    public static void main(String[]argrs){

    Scanner dir = new Scanner (System.in);
    int numStudents,student1,student2,student3;
    double average;
    int sum =0;

    System.out.println("Enter the number of students");
    numStudents = dir.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the grade for Student1");
    student1= dir.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the grade for Student2");
    student2= dir.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the grade for Student3");
    student3= dir.nextInt();

    int [] grades= new int[numStudents];
    grades [0]=student1;
    grades [1]=student2;
    grades [2]=student3;

    for (int i = 0;i<=numStudents;i++){
        if (grades[i]>0 && grades[i]<=100){
        sum += grades[i];

        }
    }    
    average = (double)sum/numStudents;
    System.out.println("Average is "+ average);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. It's not entirely clear what you are asking for, here. Can you please edit your question to explain what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be :

```
 for (int i = 0;i<numStudents;i++){
    if (grades[i]>0 && grades[i]<=100){
    sum += grades[i];

    }
}
```

Instead of

```
 for (int i = 0;i<=numStudents;i++){
```

This is because an array of length `x` has elements from index `0` till index `x - 1`.

EDIT : To print an error message if one of the grades exceeds 100 you could use the `else` statement.

Like this :

```
for (int i = 0;i<numStudents;i++){
    if (grades[i]>0 && grades[i]<=100){
       sum += grades[i];
    }
    else
       System.out.println("invalid grade, Try again later");
}
```

However it would be cleaner to make sure the grade is `0 <= grade <= 100` when the user is inputting it. Like this :

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the grade for Student1");
} while((student1 = reader.nextInt()) > 100 || student1 < 0);
```

Now you can be sure that at the time of the for loop the grade for `student1` is correct (between 0 and 100).

Comment: hey thanks 4d quick response...i just altered it and behold it runs : please how do i incorporate a code that prints out "invalid grade, Try again later" in the program ,each time i enter a grade that exceeds 100

Comment: @vinnygod I edited my answer in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be in your for loop here:

```
for (int i = 0;i<=numStudents;i++){
```

Since your array is of size `numStudents` you should scan it from index 0 to index `numStudents-1`, meaning:

```
for (int i = 0;i < numStudents;i++){
```

(no equals, just less than).

Comment: hey thanks 4d quick response...i just altered it and behold it runs : please how do i incorporate a code that prints out "invalid grade, Try again later" in the program ,each time i enter a grade that exceeds 100

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array with

```
int [] grades= new int[numStudents];
```

and `numStudents=3` it means you have indexes `0`, `1`, and `2` to give you three of them starting at `0`.

```
for (int i = 0;i<=numStudents;i++){
```

will iterate between 0, 1, 2, 3 with the last one not being an index.

What you meant was

```
for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
```

Note you could have written.

```
int count = 0;
for (int grade : grades) {
    if (grade > 0 && grades <= 100) {
        sum += grades[i];
        count++;
    }
}
// you need to use count instead of numStudents
average = (double)sum/count;
```

or even

```
double average = IntStream.of(grades)
                          .filter(g -> g > 0 && g <= 100)
                          .boxed()
                          .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(i -> i));
```

Comment: hey thanks 4d quick response...i just altered it and behold it runs : please how do i incorporate a code that prints out "invalid grade, Try again later" in the program ,each time i enter a grade that exceeds 100